# Multiply multiple columns based on if then logic

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to formulate vba logic that will multiply cells in one column by other columns based on the header name. For example if I have the data below: 
[image]

In column I, I'm trying to multiply cell range A2:A11 by B2:B11 by D2:D11. Since the value in A1 is the same as the left two characters in D1 and B1 is the same as the right two characters in D1. In column J it would be cell range A2:A11 multiply by E2:E11 and so on. The result should look as follows: 
[image]

The macro is attempting to do this by comparing the cell values in cell rage A1:B1 to D1:G1, but what I cannot figure out is how to multiply 3 cell ranges together.

Vba:

```
Sub IfThenLogic2()
Dim SrchRng1 As Range, cel1 As Range
Dim SrchRng2 As Range, cel2 As Range

Set SrchRng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B1")
Set SrchRng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F1:G1")


c = 13

For Each cel1 In SrchRng1

    For Each cel2 In SrchRng2
    If (cel1.Value = Left(cel2.Value, 2) Or cel1.Value = Right(cel2.Value, 2)) Then
    'If cel1.Value = cel2.Value Then
        For r = 2 To 11
            Cells(r, c).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & cel1.Offset(r - 1, 0).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & "*" & cel2.Offset(r - 1, 0).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ""
        Next r
        c = c + 1
        End If
    Next cel2
Next cel1


End Sub
```

The `OR` operator produces (as expected):
[image]

Is there perhaps a better way to accomplish this by not using `for each loops`?
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Your column naming/lookup scheme seems unnecessarily ambiguous. Can you explain further?

Comment: How come Column I is using three columns to multiply, but the others (J, K, L) don't? Do you need to multiply all three columns, or should it be two?

Comment: It has to do with the column names, becuase in column D the name (D1) is A1_A5 it needs to multiply its number (column D) with both columns listed A1 (Column A) and A5 (Column B).  At least that is what I am seeing.  And since the other columns only have one of the A1 of A5 in their names only those columns get multiplied.

Comment: Sure, my data is defined by these headers A1, A2, A1_A2, and so on. The headers will always be in this A# or A#_A# format, but the numbers will change from case to case. Further more if in a case I have A1, A2, A1_A2, my need is to multiply my the data in A1_A2, by the data in the column A1 and the data in the column A2. I was trying to develop a macro that would look at the left and right two characters of the header, e.g, A1_A2, and look in a range for columns with the headers A1 and A2. If A1 and A2 are found, then multiply the data in these two columns by the data in the column with A1_A2.

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it in VBA:

```
Sub IfThenLogic2()
Dim SrchRng1 As Range, cel1 As Range
Dim SrchRng2 As Range, cel2 As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set SrchRng1 = sht.Range("A1:B1")
Set SrchRng2 = sht.Range("D1:G1")


Dim title() As String
c = 13

For Each cel1 In SrchRng1

    For Each cel2 In SrchRng2
    title = Split(cel2, "_")
        For i = LBound(title) To UBound(title)
            If title(i) = cel1.Value Then
            'If cel1.Value = cel2.Value Then
            For r = 2 To 11
                If sht.Cells(r, c).HasFormula Then
                    sht.Cells(r, c).Formula = sht.Cells(r, c).Formula & "*" & cel1.Offset(r - 1, 0).Address
                Else
                    sht.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=" & cel1.Offset(r - 1, 0).Address & "*" & cel2.Offset(r - 1, 0).Address
                End If
            Next r

            End If
        Next i
        c = c + 1
    Next cel2
    c = 13
Next cel1


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottCraner! I'll definitely have to read up on Split,  and L/RBound.

Comment: @user3290799 That was just encase you ever want more than two columns in the title.  The problem was two things. 1. find out if it has a formula and add to it. 2. your counter needed a reset.  And just looking it over again, The second one could be dispatched if you switch your two outer loops.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a normal (non-array) formula to do it. Just enter it into cell `I2` and copy as needed:

```
=INDEX($D2:$G2,MATCH(I$1,$D$1:$G$1,))    *    IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$B2,MATCH(LEFT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,)),1)   *    IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$B2,MATCH(RIGHT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,)),1)
```

If you want this automated, you can use this VBA:

```
Public Sub excelhero()
    [i2].Formula = "=INDEX($D2:$G2,MATCH(I$1,$D$1:$G$1,))    *    IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$B2,MATCH(LEFT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,)),1)   *    IFERROR(INDEX($A2:$B2,MATCH(RIGHT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,)),1)"
    [i2].Copy [i2:L11]
    [i2:L11].Value = [i2:L1].Value   '<-- replaces formulas with literal values
End Sub
```

Comment: @user3290799 Is there something wrong with this approach in your case?

Comment: The problem is that the number of A# and A#_A# columns is variable. In one case I could have columns with A1, A2, A3, A4, A1_A2, A1_A5, A2_A3, A4_A8, which based on my spacing conventions would only occupy columns A:I.

Comment: You could use named ranges in that case. This should still work.

Comment: Oh OK, thanks ! I'm not really sure whats going on with the brackets.

Comment: @user3290799 You can learn about the [square brackets here](http://blog.excelhero.com/2010/06/05/when_working_in_vba_we/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a formula I got an Array Formula that works.

Here's how the Data is laid out (you may need to adjust formula if it's different for you):

[image]

The formula to put in `I2` is:
`=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$G$1,LEFT(I$1,2)),COUNTIF($A$1:$G$1,RIGHT(I$1,2))),INDEX($A2:$G2,,MATCH(LEFT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,0))*INDEX($A2:$G2,,MATCH(RIGHT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,0))*INDEX($A2:$G2,,MATCH(I$1,$A$1:$G$1,0)),INDEX($A2:$G2,,MATCH(RIGHT(I$1,2),$A$1:$B$1,0))*INDEX($A2:$G2,,MATCH(I$1,$A$1:$G$1,0)))`

<s>and confirm with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.</s>  Just hit `ENTER`.

This is basically three index/match formulas multiplied together.  The Index/Matching is using the left and right 2 characters of your header to find the column with the appropriate number.

PS: Just for anyone else, here's the table of info in text form (so you can copy/paste). The brackets represent an empty column separating the others.

```
A1  A5  []  A1_A5   A3_A1   A3_A5   A9_A5   []  A1_A5   A3_A1   A3_A5   A9_A5
16  16      61      17      38      46                  
41  6       6       58      22      95                  
39  38      19      37      92      14                  
98  99      64      74      53      88                  
14  35      92      47      34      58                  
18  76      93      20      54      25                  
94  47      78      37      96      44                  
32  25      61      61      66      39                  
9   74      31      43      75      22                  
8   19      14      83      9       89
```

Comment: Ah, you're right! I was playing around earlier and had it as an array formula. I must've forgot I removed that part.

Comment: Thank you for the cool formula @BruceWayne! The problem is that the number of A# and A#_A# columns is variable. In one case I could have columns with A1, A2, A3, A4, A1_A2, A1_A5, A2_A3, A4_A8, which based on my spacing conventions would only occupy columns A:I.